# Meteor-React Pass function with createContainer

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

Is it possible to a pass a function with `createContainer` in Meteor with React and `react-meteor-data`?

For example:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import App from 'App.jsx';
export default AppContainer = createContainer(({ }) => {
    const do = () => {
        console.log("do");
    }
    return {
        do
    };
}, App);
```

And then in App:

```
const App = ({ do }) => (
    <button onClick={do}>Do something</button>

);

export default App;
```

Comment: It should be possible, as React props are allowed to be functions. Doesn't the code above work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, when I click a button with a passed function just nothing happens, without any error.

Comment: @aedm I solved it by invoking the method with parenthesis, I do not really know why this was working then, but it worked. Thank you so far your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question by my own. I do not know why this was working then, but if I call the passed function like this

```
 <button onClick={do()}>Do something</button>
```

Then my code is working. I thought I could also invoke passed function without parenthesis, but this seems to be not the case.

But thanks so for the help :)